# Undefined offset: 1 in CRM_Utils_Check_Security->guessUrl()

Tags: debugging

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in CRM_Utils_Check_Security->guessUrl() (line 330 of /home/saintfran/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Security.php).
```

I found the following on the issue queue and the old forums but they say they are fixed and that it's related to windows. I'm  not on a windows machine. I'm hosted on civihosting with 4.6.2.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15214
http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32544.0

Comment: What version of CiviCRM do you have ?

Comment: Sorry forgot that.  4.6.2. Now I'm getting access denied error for all admin pages.

Comment: I don't think the access denied is linked to the notice.

Comment: Maybe not but it's weird.  I haven't changed any permissions

Comment: are you logged in ? if you browse a website with http / https and you are logged in on http and civicrm force https, you won't be able to acces civicrm pages until you log on the https version of the site

Comment: That's what it is then.  Whew.

Answer (score 3):

So I think I found the fix.

I had my Images directory under Admin=>Directories to the following:
/home/my_site/www/www/civi_images

The Image Upload URL under Admin=>Resource URLS to the following:
https://saintfrancisocc.org/civi_images

When I upgraded to 4.6.2 is when I started getting the error. I checked that line in the Security.php file and it referred to the uploadurl as samuelsov stated. So I thought I'd try changing that to something else and see if it fixed it.

I changed the Images director under Admin=>Directories to the following:
/home/my_site/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/civi_images/

And changed the Image Upload URL under Admin=>Resource URLS to the following:
https://saintfrancisocc.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/civi_images/

I went and refreshed and no more error. So it appears that civi 4.6.2 doesn't like the upload directory to be at the root

Answer (score 1):

The function `CRM_Utils_Check_Security->guessUrl()`, as far as i understand, is only used to check if there is security problem in the configuration of your upload path.

It's seems to be a bug, but not one that as any impact on CiviCRM functionality.
I don't think it could lead to a problems like access denied or something like that.

Comment: What sort of security problem? A folder permission issue?

Comment: Yes, the files in the upload directory shouldn't be accessible using a browser. If it is the case, CiviCRM will display a security warning.